# How do I manually cast value to datatype of column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with a table of user input that I'm trying to compare to the current values in the table within SQL.

I'm trying to get the rows where the items are different than what's in the table, but the issue I'm running into is an input value may be `2` when the value in the table is casted as a `DECIMAL` so the actual value in the table is `2.00`. I want to consider those to be the same.

My thought process is that I want to somehow cast my input into the datatype of the column, then compare.

**My Table**

```
-----------------------------------
ColumnName   |   Value
-----------------------------------
<user-id>    | 1
<user-date>  | 2021-06-30T00:00:00
```

**Incoming Values**

```
-----------------------------------
ColumnName   |   Value
-----------------------------------
<user-id>    | 1
<user-date>  | 2021-06-30
```

**Edit**
Here is an example of what my issue is. `2` and `2.00` should equate to the same.

```
DECLARE @storageTable TABLE(id INT, cost DECIMAL(13,2), orderedTime DATETIME)
DECLARE @incomingJson VARCHAR(MAX)='{"id":"1", "cost":"2", "orderedTime":"6/24/2021"}'

INSERT INTO @storageTable (Id, cost, orderedTime) VALUES(1, 2, '6/24/2021')


SELECT *
FROM @storageTable st
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON((SELECT st.* FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER))) cv
        INNER JOIN OPENJSON(@incomingJson) ua ON ua.[key]=cv.[key]
WHERE st.id=1   
    AND cv.[value] <> ua.[value]
```

Comment: The *real* problem here is your design. Don't have a column called `ColumnName` have columns called `UserId` and `UserDate` which are **strongly** typed. ERP systems rarely work well in an RDBMS.

Comment: So you want to cast a date column?

Comment: @Larnu, I don't actually have a column named that. Long story short, the data coming in is a key-value json string, where the key is the column name, and I am trying to determine whether it needs an update or not. I only want to update if there is value that is different in the incoming string. That being said, I've managed to write a query that gets me my columns and the values by row. That's why you're seeing it like that.

Comment: @AT-2017 In this case, yes. However, I can't hard-code it to just be a date. I need to dynamically cast it to whatever data-type the table column is.

Comment: Sounds like the sample data you've provided us isn't representative then. For a strongly typed  numerical value both `2` and `2.00` are the same value, so I don't understand what the problem is. Unless you're storing numerical data as a `(n)varchar`? If so, that's a design flaw unto itself and you *need* to fix that.

Comment: @Larnu The issue is that since the incoming values are strings, it isn't typed to the corresponding data type for that column. That being said, ```"2"``` isn't equal to ```2.00```. That's why I'm trying to see how to cast a type to a specific table column type dynamically.

Comment: But when you *compare* that value to the column it will be implicitly cast, @Brandon . `(n)varchar` have some of the lowest [data type precendeces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) so `'2' = 2`, `'2' = 2.00`  would both result in TRUE because the `varchar` would be implicitly converted to an `int`/`decimal`. iot would, however, fail if you passed `'2.00'` to an `int` column, as it isn't a valid `int` (integers don't have decimal places)

Comment: @Larnu I just added some SQL to try to better explain my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're severely overly complicating the problem. Define your columns in `OPENJSON`, with strong typing, and then the values can be compared properly; don't unpivot it all.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM @storageTable sT
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(@incomingJson) 
                 WITH (id int,
                       val DECIMAL(13,2)) iJ
WHERE sT.id <> iJ.id
   OR sT.val <> iJ.val;
```

Comment: This is definitely A solution. I'm trying to avoid re-defining the columns like that because the table has an insane number of columns which starts to make this solution not so awesome. I was hoping to be able to somehow capture the datatype of the column in ```@storageTable``` and use that to cast the ```iJ``` to that type.

Comment: If you unpivot your data then you are "resigning" to converting them all to the same data type, @Brandon . I'm starting to smell an ["XY Problem"](http://xyproblem.info) here, if I am honest. Perhaps you should just be performing a `MERGE` or Upsert. Or filtering the data in your JSON on a "last updated time" value, which you should be storing in the table too; then you can just compare that value.

Comment: I'm aware that this isn't an idea scenario, and if we had full control over what was being passed to us, we wouldn't design it this way. Ultimately, I'm getting a json string with 100+ column names/values (some columns that we don't even have in our copy of the table) and I need to compare that to what's currently stored in our table and see if that row needs to be updated or not.

Comment: Hence why I've pivoted my storage table into rows to get the current column/values to compare to my OPENJSON pivot. If there's a better way to handle this poop sandwich that we're dealing with, I'm all ears.

Comment: @Brandon - either trust in the implicit conversions to validate the data type, or use TRY_CAST/TRY_CONVERT to attempt to convert to the appropriate data type.  If the value cannot be converted it will be returned as a NULL.